# How do I write an algorithm to break the Caesar Cipher?

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to do an exercise in a programming book, one of the exercises being decrypting ciphertext that uses the [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) with an unknown shift.

Here's the ciphertext:

> `HVWGWGHVSPSGHQCADIHSFSLSFQWGSWVOJSSJSFSLDSFWSBQSR`

I don't know the expected output because I haven't determined the algorithm yet.

I've written the following algorithm to try to decrypt it using the Caesar cipher, but this is as far as I've gotten. How do I decrypt this in C#?

```
string s = "HVWGWGHVSPSGHQCADIHSFSLSFQWGSWVOJSSJSFSLDSFWSBQSR";

int[] freq = new int[26];

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
  // converting 
  string temp = s.Substring(i, 1); 

  // converting to an array
  int itemp = (int)temp.ToCharArray()[0];

  freq[itemp - 65]++;  
}

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(i + " " + freq[i]);
}
```

Comment: the output string should use the shift of the most repeated letter then used that to decipher the String s= HVWGWGHVSPSGHQCADIHSFSLSFQWGSWVOJSSJSFSLDSFWSBQSR to something else using the shift. I have gotten to the point that i get the number each letter is repeated thats all. I am not getting an output of a string, im not sure were proceed after finding what letter repeats.

Comment: These are details to edit into your question. We're still missing what you believe the output string should actually be, versus what you're getting.

Comment: The alphabetic shift should use the most common letter then use that to change the string into the deciphered one. Im not sure how else to explain it

Comment: Please stop putting question details in your comments, and [edit] your question to include them there instead. Adding details to comments means we can't see them when reading your question, and they're quite often important to finding a solution. Burying them in the clutter of comments isn't helpful to us (or you when you're the one trying to get help). Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Since this appears to be an assignment, I'm not going to give you the answer in C#.  I will explain the algorithm and give a solution in Python.

The Caeser Cipher works by shifting an alphabet "N" number of spaces.  If you have an alphabet set up in an array:

```
array = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
```

This is an easy way to manipulate the alphabet to see what different shifts would look like.

The next thing to do is to count the number of occurrences of each letter in the cipher:

```
count = {}                                                                                                                                                                       
encrypted_string = "HVWGWGHVSPSGHQCADIHSFSLSFQWGSWVOJSSJSFSLDSFWSBQSR"        
for s in encrypted_string:                                                    
    if count.has_key(s):                                                      
        count[s]+=1                                                           
    else:                                                                     
        count[s] = 1                                                          
                                                                              
most_occured = 1                                                              
last_found = ""                                                               
for key in count:                                                             
    if count[key] > most_occured: 
        last_found = key                                                      
        most_occured = count[key]
```

This is important because since the Ceasar Cipher uses a normal alphabet shifted, the resulting ciphertext can be figured out by frequency analysis, just as a normal alphabet can.

In the English language, [the letter "E" appears most often](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis).  It stands to reason that there's a good chance the letter that will appear most often in your cipher text will be a shifted letter that corresponds to "E".

Since `S` appears most frequently in your cipher text (a total of 13 times), and given that we know that `E` occurs most often in the english language we know that `S` is likely `E`.

Given also that we know this is a Caesar Cipher, we can assume the rest of the letters are shifted just like `S` was shifted. and `E` is the 5th letter, we can do the following math:

> Position in Alphabet of Most Occurring letter in Cipher text - Position of most occuring letter in alphabet = Number of places to shift ciphertext to decrypt

Or, more succinctly:

> Position of "S" - Position of "E" = 14:
>
> 19 - 5 = 14

That means that every letter should be left shifted by 14 places:

```
decrypted_string = ""                                                  

for s in encrypted_string:                                                
       decrypted_string += array[array.index(s)-14]                         

print decrypted_string
```

This outputs the following deciphered text:

> THISISTHEBESTCOMPUTEREXERCISEIHAVEEVEREXPERIENCED

I've purposefully left a few things out, for instance how to actually do the calculation where I've hardcoded "14" in the second algorithm.  Some items need to be left up to those conducting the assignment.  There is also probably a faster and easier way to do some of the things I did; I was doing this for fun.

Comment: What is the story behind E being a base factor to define the shift key ? Finding the most used letter is fine I just don't understand why E becomes a base factor to define the actual shift.

Comment: @Prix given the assumption that the plaintext is English, guessing that the most frequently occurring letter in the ciphertext represents E in the plaintext is a standard starting point for breaking substitution ciphers.  Since the Caesar cipher is a simple rotation rather than an arbitrary permutation, once the shift of one letter is determined, the same shift applies to all letters.

Answer (score 3):

How many possible keys are there for a Caesar cypher?  Hint: not a large number.  Given a computer it is perfectly possible to try all the keys in turn.  You then have to think of a way to identify the correct key from your output data.  The human eye is one alternative.

The technique is sometimes called "Running down the alphabet".  It is covered in the Wikipedia article.